# Is there an alternative, vectored way to write the to_array function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting, ragged

Suppose we have a ragged, nested sequence like the following:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.ones((10, 20))
y = np.zeros((10, 20))
a = [[0, x], [y, 1]]
```

and want to create a *full* `numpy` array that broadcasts the ragged sub-sequences (to match the maximum dimension of any other sub-sequence, in this case `(10,20)`) where necessary. First, we might try to use `np.array(a)`, which yields the warning:

> `VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray`

By changing to `np.array(a, dtype=object)`, we do get an array. However, this is an array of objects rather than floats, and retains the ragged subsequences, which have not been broadcasted as desired. To fix this, I created a new function `to_array` which takes a (possibly ragged, nested) sequence and a shape and returns a full numpy array of that shape:

```py
    def to_array(a, shape):
        a = np.array(a, dtype=object)
        b = np.empty(shape)
        for index in np.ndindex(a.shape):
            b[index] = a[index]
        return b
    
    b = np.array(a, dtype=object)
    c = to_array(a, (2, 2, 10, 20))
    
    print(b.shape, b.dtype) # prints (2, 2) object
    print(c.shape, c.dtype) # prints (2, 2, 10, 20) float64
```

Note that `c`, not `b`, is the desired result. However, `to_array` relies on a for loop over [nindex](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html), and Python for loops are slow for big arrays.

Is there an alternative, vectorized way to write the `to_array` function?

Comment: "that broadcasts the ragged sub-sequences (to match the maximum dimension of any other sub-sequence, in this case (10,20)) where necessary. " Sorry, I can't follow this. Could you show a small example that includes the exact, complete desired output (small enough that you can produce it by hand, but big enough to make it clear what you're looking for)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `c` is the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Given the target shape, a few iterations doesn't seem overly expensive:

```
In [35]: C = np.empty((A.shape+x.shape), x.dtype)                                                    
In [36]: for idx in np.ndindex(A.shape): 
    ...:     C[idx] = A[idx] 
    ...:
```

Alternatively you could replace the `0` and `1` with the appropraite (10,20) arrays.  Here you've already created those, `x` and `y`:

```
In [37]: D = np.array([[y,x],[y,x]])                                                                 
In [38]: np.allclose(C,D)                                                                            
Out[38]: True
```

In general a few iterations on a complex task are ok.  Keep in mind that (many) operations on an object dtype array are actually slower than operations on an equivalent list.  It's the whole-array compiled operations on a numeric array that are relatively fast.  That's not your case.

But

```
C[0,0,:,:] = 0
```

uses broadcasting - all (10,20) values of `C[0,0]` are filled with the scalar `0` via broadcasting.

```
C[0,1,:,:] = x
```

is a different broadcasting, where the RHS matches the left.  It's unreasonable to expect `numpy` to handle both cases with one broadcasting operation.